# Java - Maybe bug at JComboBox Render inside JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, render, jcombobox

I would like to know why this is happening. 
Its a render bug?!
The text on the selected item at JComboBox has small height and JComboBox its above the text why?

How can I fix this this?

I don't know if its a bug of the render or maybe I am doing something wrong.

Here is an image, much better to explain :)

[image]

Thanks alot in advance!

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you illustrate.

Comment: This is the default behaviour. There is no easy fix. A JCombobox just needs more space to do its rendering.

Comment: And how can I set that space ? is there  any setHeight ? Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: table.setRowHeight(..)